# create mesh (or index buffer) for a simple shape defined by points of its base

Tags: 3d

I'm trying to create a mesh for buildings, for which I have a coordinates of points of the base (bottom). The most simple shape of the base is a rectangular one, but it can be more complex. But the points in the base are always oriented and always connected.

Here is the image of what 3d shape I'd like to get:
[image]

I can fill the vertex buffer - for the box I first use the coordinates of the base for points 0-4, then transform them upwards (on the Y axis) and use them again as points 5-7.

I have read that I have to define the triangles counter-clockwise, and was able to fill the index buffer (by hand) for the rectangular box. But I don't like the idea of doing that by hand for each shape, so there surely is (probably easy) way to do that in code.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to have a method which takes 4 points, for example 0, 4, 5, 1 in this case and creates 2 triangles that makes a plane and return a list of 6 indices. Then you only need to iterate through all the points in groups of four.

So in your case: 
first input is: 0, 4, 5, 1 this creates the output indices: 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 5. 
second input is: 1, 5, 6, 2 this creates the output indices: 1, 5, 2, 2, 5, 6.
etc etc

Looping through the points is easily achievable since the points are organized in a system. If you keep track of how many points there are in the bottom you can easily obtain the point that is "above" any other point.

For example, if you want to loop through all the points in groups of four:

```
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfPointsInBottom; i++)
    {
         listOfIndices = getIndicesFromFourPoints(i,(i+numberOfPointsInBottom),i+1,(i+numberOfPointsInBottom+1))
    }
```

In this example the input for the funktion in the first iteration would be: 0, 4, 1, 5.

This is how I did it when I needed to connect the vertices of a cylinder defined by any number of edges, I hope you understand my line of thought.